# Angularjs - Modal dialog is shown in default page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to show a modal popup dialog from HTML template. Unfortunately HTML page isn't popup dialog
but the HTML code is pasted to default HTML page. Below is the controller that I used.

```
app.controller('sortFiles', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $uibModal) {

    $scope.Action = function () {
         var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: '/skanner/html/test.html',
            windowClass: 'center-modal',
             controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
             controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            size: 'sm',
            //controllerAs: '$ctrl',
          resolve: {
                //items: function () {
                //    return $scope.items;
               // }
            }
    });
```

And HTML default page.

```
<div id="idDivButtonSort" style="width:200px;"  ng-controller="sortFiles" ng-mouseup="MouseUp()" ng-mousedown="MouseDown()" ng-click="Action()" >
    Sortuj
</div>
```

HTML code from test.html is not shown in modal dialog but is paste to top default page.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the problem. 'bootstrap.min.css' was incorrect.